# sqlite queries returning errors - can't work out why

Tags: javascript, jquery, scraperwiki

Not sure this is a side-effect of a custom function in sqlite, but I was trying to use the queries to power a form. (here's a rough demo http://www.thisisstaffordshire.co.uk/images/localpeople/ugc-images/275796/binaries/GPformMap4.html)

Slight problem is that if I use a query using certain terms the query returns data:

[https://api.scraperwiki.com/api/1.0/datastore/sqlite?format=htmltable&name=geoutil&apikey=a083014f-1103-47ee-86aa-e30db4aa4762&query=select%20distance(Latitude%2C%20Longitude%2C%2052.951458%2C%20-2.032748)%20as%20distance%2C%20*%20from%20%60swdata%60%20where%20electronic_prescription%20%3D%20%22Yes%22%20and%20early_appointments%20like%20%22%258%25%22%20order%20by%20distance%20asc%20limit%2010](https://api.scraperwiki.com/api/1.0/datastore/sqlite?format=htmltable&name=geoutil&apikey=a083014f-1103-47ee-86aa-e30db4aa4762&query=select%20distance%28Latitude,%20Longitude,%2052.951458,%20-2.032748%29%20as%20distance,%20%2a%20from%20%60swdata%60%20where%20electronic_prescription%20=%20%22Yes%22%20and%20early_appointments%20like%20%22%258%25%22%20order%20by%20distance%20asc%20limit%2010)

But others not including the electronic_prescription tag, don't and return the following error:

{u'error': u'sqliteexecute: sqlite3.Error: user-defined function raised exception'}

[https://api.scraperwiki.com/api/1.0/datastore/sqlite?format=htmltable&name=geoutil&apikey=a083014f-1103-47ee-86aa-e30db4aa4762&query=select%20distance%28Latitude%2C%20Longitude%2C%2052.951458%2C%20-2.032748%29%20as%20distance%2C%20*%20from%20%60swdata%60%20where%20early_appointments%20like%20%22%258%25%22%20order%20by%20distance%20asc%20limit%2010](https://api.scraperwiki.com/api/1.0/datastore/sqlite?format=htmltable&name=geoutil&apikey=a083014f-1103-47ee-86aa-e30db4aa4762&query=select%20distance%28Latitude,%20Longitude,%2052.951458,%20-2.032748%29%20as%20distance,%20%2a%20from%20%60swdata%60%20where%20early_appointments%20like%20%22%258%25%22%20order%20by%20distance%20asc%20limit%2010)

I think the problem is down to an error using a custom function to return a distance based on two lat/long-defined points.

What have I done wrong? More importantly, is it easy to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David Jones has answered this question on the ScraperWiki email list. You can read the answer here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/scraperwiki/Rh6qkNHiRjI